# Getting collection values based on document reference in firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire2

I am devloping Ionic5 - angular app using angularfirebase and I have following collections in firestore database where partners is array of documentreference to Users. I want to display all apartments list along with partners' name (first name and last name from users collection). I am able to write query to get the data properly when i query for one apartment using its ID and get other details from other collections. However when I am trying to get all apartments with all other details as in this case users, I am struggling.

[image: Firestore DB Structure]

[image: db structure]

method for getting the details for one apartment when I have apartment id:

```
getApartmentById(aptId: string) {
return this.afs.collection('Apartment').doc<apartment>(aptId).snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(apart => {
      return combineLatest(
        of(apart),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.collection<address>('Address', ref => ref.where('ApartmentID', '==', apart.payload.ref)).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(addresses => {
                const data = addresses[0].payload.doc.data() as address;
                const id = addresses[0].payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        ),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.doc<apartmentType>(apart.payload.data().Type).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(atype => {
                //console.log(atype.payload.id);
                const data = atype.payload.data() as apartmentType;
                const id = atype.payload.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        ),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.collection<phone>('Phone', ref => ref.where('ApartmentID', '==', apart.payload.ref)).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(phones => {
                const data = phones[0].payload.doc.data() as phone;
                const id = phones[0].payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        )
      )
    }),
    map(([apart, add, room, phn]) => {
      //console.log(add);
      return {
        apartment: apart.payload.data(),
        address: add[0],
        apartmenttype: room[0],
        phone: phn[0]
      }

    })
  );
```

}

Can someone please help me how can I get the details for all apartments and join on users to get first name. I am expecting following out put.

```
[
  {
    apartmentName: "Some value",
    partners:[
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"},
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"}
      ]
  },
  {
    apartmentName: "Some value",
    partners:[
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"},
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"}
      ]
  },
  {
    apartmentName: "Some value",
    partners:[
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"},
      {firstname:"some value", lastname:"some value"}
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: no answer to this questions??

Answer (score 1):

With this two functions should be able to achieve it.

The Idea is to use a functions similar to the one you had, that gets each apartment, And the second function gets all the apartments reference in to an array, and with map apply the first function to all the elements of the array.

```
getApartment(apt: DocumentReference) {

return apt.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(apart => {
      return combineLatest(
        of(apart),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.collection<address>('Address', ref => ref.where('ApartmentID', '==', apart.payload.ref)).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(addresses => {
                const data = addresses[0].payload.doc.data() as address;
                const id = addresses[0].payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        ),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.doc<apartmentType>(apart.payload.data().Type).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(atype => {
                //console.log(atype.payload.id);
                const data = atype.payload.data() as apartmentType;
                const id = atype.payload.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        ),
        combineLatest(
          this.afs.collection<phone>('Phone', ref => ref.where('ApartmentID', '==', apart.payload.ref)).snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              map(phones => {
                const data = phones[0].payload.doc.data() as phone;
                const id = phones[0].payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
              })
            )
        )
      )
    }),
    map(([apart, add, room, phn]) => {
      //console.log(add);
      return {
        apartment: apart.payload.data(),
        address: add[0],
        apartmenttype: room[0],
        phone: phn[0]
      }

    })
  );   
}

getAllApartments(){
    return this.afs.collection('Apartment').listDocuments().then({docsRef =>
        return docsRef.map(getApartment());
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But thats not going to work because if you noticed partners is array inside each apartment document and each element from partners array has to be mapped with Users document.

Comment: in JS the arrays can be ob Objects, and getApartment returns the same structure as in your code, the only modification in your code ist that it works with the reference instead of the ID. And the one that gets all gets the references and then maps the references with getApartment which gives the apartment structure and map puts them in the array.

Comment: May be i am not getting it. Can you please help writing simple query for the output I mentioned in my question based on the data structure from the screenshots? Thanks in advance!